# C# база данных. Как связать списки?

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms

У меня есть такая форма

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии кнопки "Добавить автора" открывается следующая форма с 4 `textbox`.
ФИО добавленного автора заносится в `listBox1` на форме `Form1`, при выборе элемента из `listBox` активируется кнопка "Добавить произведение". В форме с добавлением произведения также присутствует 4 `textbox`.

Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе элемента в `listbox1` формы1 выводилась информация этого писателя со всеми добавленными произведениями? Другими словами, как связать список литературы с определенным автором?

Comment: а где структура бд?

Comment: Ага, и какая ORM используется?

Comment: пример привязки иерархических данных к контрола посмотрите в ответе -- [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478616)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала определитесь, где вы хотите хранить свои данные. Можете использовать подход Code First для Entity Framework. 
Создайте два класса:

```
public class Artist //автор(исполнитель)
{
  public int ID {get;set;} //первичный ключ
  public string FirstName {get;set}
//и т.д.
  public virtual ICollection<Track> Tracks {get;set;}
  public Artist()
  {
     Tracks = new List<Track>();
  }
}

public class Track //трек(произведение)
{
   public int ID {get;set;} //первичный ключ

   public int ArtistId {get;set;} //внешний ключ
   public Artist Artist {get;set;} //свойство навигации
   public string Name {get;set;}
//и т.д.
}
```

Такой код создаст связь один-ко-многим между вашими сущностями. Связать коллекции авторов и произведений можно будет, вызывая метод 
`System.Linq.Iqueryable<T>.Include<T,object>(Expression<Func<T,object>> path) where T : class` на экземпляре сущности. В сам метод просто передадите лямбда-выражение, определяющее, что нужно "связать".