# Как привязать контролы к иерархическим данным?

Tags: c#, winforms, binding

Возможно ли в WinForms привязать контролы к иерархическим данным?
Например, есть следующий xml:

```
<data>
    <level1 name='l11'>
        <level2 name='l12'>
            <level3 name='l13' />
        </level2>
    </level1>
    <level1 name='l21'>
        <level2 name='l22'>
            <level3 name='l23' />
        </level2>
    </level1>
</data>
```

Надо все значения level1 name вывести в один DataGridView. Все level2 name вывести в другой DataGridView. И все level3 name - в третий.
Значения должны выводиться с учетом иерархии. Например, если в DataGridView для level1 текущей строкой является l11, то в DataGridView для level2 выводится l12.
Значения в каждом из DataGridView можно добавлять/удалять/редактировать и при этом должен сразу выводиться измененный xml.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это пример для раздельных контолов и фиксированного уровня иерархии. То, что вы описываете, это обычный Master-Details (с тремя фиксированными уровнями вместо двух). Под иерархическими датасорсами обычно подразумевают древовидные структуры из однородных элементов - папки на диске, например. А под иерархическими контролами - цельные элементы управления без заранее известного уровня иерархии (TreeView, например. а не три раздельных грида)

Comment: _"под иерархическими датасорсами обычно подразумевают древовидные структуры из однородных элементов"_ -- такие структуры хранят в виде таблиц где есть id и parentId. привязка работает также. пример в ответе -- [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478676)

Comment: Там иерархические данные, но неирерархическое отображение - нет никакой визуальной связи на расстояни дальше чем один уровень. чтобы добраться от 0 уровня во 2-й - нужно руками найти и выбрать промежуточную строку.  А не просто распахнуть текущий элемент, как в tree view. Представьте что строк там несколько тысяч - и станет очевидным, что такое представление не позволяет увидеть иерархию и свободно перемещаться по ней. (Кто-то уже минусанул, особо не разбираясь).

Comment: _"не просто распахнуть текущий элемент, как в tree view."_ -- вот как-раз с treeview сложно, когда много уровней. попробуйте в проводнике найти самую вложенную папку) очеыидно, что намного проще работать со списками. и можно сделать treelist.
и [вопрос был о привязке к таблицам "сама на себя"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33519/discussion-between-pashapash-and-stack) -- т.е. когда есть nested relation. и как показывает пример в ответе - это возможно. а про привязку к treeview потом напишу.

Answer (score 2):

В WinForms у контролов есть свойства DataSource и DataMember, которые позволяют привязывать контрол к источнику данных.
Для создания xml-редактора в WinForms, как показано на рис., достаточно следующего кода.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
class Program {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var d = Model.Create();
        var l1 = new DataGridView() {
            Bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 249, 400),
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None,
            ColumnHeadersVisible = false,
            DataSource = d,
            DataMember = "level1"
        };
        var l2 = new DataGridView() {
            Bounds = new Rectangle(250, 0, 249, 199),
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None,
            ColumnHeadersVisible = false,
            DataSource = d,
            DataMember = "level1.level1_level2"
        };
        var l3 = new DataGridView() {
            Bounds = new Rectangle(250, 200, 249, 200),
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None,
            ColumnHeadersVisible = false,
            DataSource = d,
            DataMember = "level1.level1_level2.level2_level3"
        };
        var t = new RichTextBox() {
            Bounds = new Rectangle(501, 0, 349, 400),
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None,
            ReadOnly = true,
            Text = Model.GetXml(d)
        };
        var f = new Form() {
            ClientSize = new Size(850, 400),
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog,
            MaximizeBox = false,
            MinimizeBox = false
        };
        f.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { l3, l2, l1, t });
        foreach (var g in f.Controls.OfType<DataGridView>())
            g.BindingContext[g.DataSource, g.DataMember].CurrentItemChanged += 
                (s, e) => t.Text = Model.GetXml(d);
        f.ShowDialog();
    }
    class Model {
        public static object Create() {
            var xml = @"
            <data>
                <level1 name='l1'>
                    <level2 name='l2'>
                        <level3 name='l3' />
                    </level2>
                </level1>
            </data>";
            var ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(new StringReader(xml));
            return ds;
        }
        public static string GetXml(object model) {
            var ds = model as DataSet;
            var sw = new StringWriter();
            ds.WriteXml(sw);
            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```