# Как таблицу со связью "сама на себя" привязать к контролам для редактирования?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть таблица со связью "сама на себя". Например:

```
Id, ParentId, Text
0,  null,     l1
1,  0,        l2
2,  1,        l3
```

В ней с помощью Id и ParentId - nested relations - определяется иерархия.
Возможно ли такую таблицу привязать к WinForms контролам?
В первом контроле надо выводить все строки, а во втором контроле надо выводить только строки, у которых parentId равен Id строки, выделенной в первом контроле.
Должна быть возможность создавать иерархию с неограниченной вложенности.
Как это можно сделать на C#? Возможно ли данные из таблицы выводить/сохранять в csv или xml?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Слева два связанных грида, а справа данные из таблицы в csv- и xml-формате.

Comment: вопрос этот возник при [обсуждении](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33519/discussion-between-pashapash-and-stack) темы привязок в WinForms.

Answer (score 2):

Таблицы c nested relations можно привязывать к контролам в WinForms.
Все что требуется для редактирования такой таблицы находится в методе Main.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

class Program {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var d = Data.LoadCsv();
        var l1 = new DataGridView() {
            Bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 249, 400),
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None,
            ColumnHeadersVisible = false,
            DataSource = d,
            DataMember = "row"
        };
        var l2 = new DataGridView() {
            Bounds = new Rectangle(250, 0, 249, 400),
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None,
            ColumnHeadersVisible = false,
            DataSource = d,
            DataMember = "row.row_row"
        };
        var trace = new Func<object, string>(data => 
                      Data.GetCsv(data) + "\n" + Data.GetXml(data));
        var t = new RichTextBox() {
            Bounds = new Rectangle(501, 0, 349, 400),
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None,
            ReadOnly = true,
            Text = trace(d)
        };
        var f = new Form() {
            ClientSize = new Size(850, 400),
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog,
            MaximizeBox = false,
            MinimizeBox = false
        };
        f.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { l2, l1, t });
        foreach (var g in f.Controls.OfType<DataGridView>())
            g.BindingContext[g.DataSource, g.DataMember].CurrentItemChanged +=
                (s, e) => t.Text = trace(d);
        f.ShowDialog();
    }
    class Data {
        public static object LoadCsv() {
            var ds = new DataSet();
            // это для теста. а обычно данные загружают из базы данных
            // например, из SQL Server с помощью SqlDataAdapter  
            ds.ReadXml(new StringReader(@"<rows>
                <row text='11'>
                    <row text='21'>
                        <row text='31' />
                        <row text='32'>
                            <row text='41' />
                </row></row></row></rows>"));
            return ds;
        }
        public static string GetXml(object model) {
            var ds = model as DataSet;
            var sw = new StringWriter();
            ds.WriteXml(sw);
            return sw.ToString();
        }
        public static string GetCsv(object model) {
            var ds = model as DataSet;
            var sw = new StringWriter();
            var cs = ds.Tables[0].Columns.OfType<DataColumn>();
            sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",\t\t", new[] { "id", "parentId", "text" }));
            var pr = ds.Tables[0].ParentRelations[0];
            var id = pr.ParentColumns[0];
            var pid = pr.ChildColumns[0];
            foreach (var r in ds.Tables[0].Rows.OfType<DataRow>())
                sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",\t\t", new[] { r[id], r[pid], r["text"] }));
            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```