# Как при создании экземпляра класса через фигурные скобки получить этот экземпляр?

Tags: c#

Есть класс

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyClass Parent { get; set; }
    public MyClass Child { get; set; }
}
```

и вот я создаю экземпляр

```
var theMyClass = new MyClass
{
    Parent = null,
    Child = new MyClass
    {
        Parent = ????? // Здесь надо указать экземпляр верхнего уровня. Но как?
    }
}
```

**UPD:**

Хочу через инициализатор, чтобы код был красивым и читабельным. Вот так будет удобнее

```
var var1 = new....
{
    {
        {

        }
    }
}
```

чем так

```
var var1 = new MyClass();
var1.Child = new MyClass();
var1.Child.Parent = var1;
var1.Child.Child = new MyClass();
var1.Child.Child.Parent = var1.Child;
// ... ну и так далее
```

Comment: А зачем Вы используете блок-инициализатор? Что мещает сделать theMyClass.Child = theMyClass?

Comment: Блок инициализации создает объект и во время этого процесса его адрес считается неопределенным извне вплоть до закрытия. Только после закрытия адрес уйдет в переменную и он станет доступным. Поэтому Вы не можете сослаться на самого себя в блоке инициализации, так как никаких ссылок на память нет. Используйте другие способы.

Comment: @nuts119, ответил на ваш комментарий в вопросе (UPD)

Comment: @AlexKrass, спасибо. Жаль.

Comment: @AlexKrass оформите вам комментарий как ответ.

Comment: в коде, для примера на пару строк, можно делать как угодно, а 
на практике, иерархии определют в виде [nested relations](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478676), из которых можно восстановить иерархию.

Comment: похоже с помощью MyClass вы создаете двусвязный список. 
в такой ситуации проще использовать готовый `System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы ищите красивый способ формирования подобных структур, то можно сначала создать "прямую" структуру, а потом дополнить ее обратными связями:

```
var obj = new MyClass
{
    Child = new MyClass
    {
        Child = new MyClass()
    }
};
BindParents(obj);

// ...

static void BindParents(MyClass obj) {
  while (obj.Child != null)
  {
    obj.Child.Parent = obj;
    obj = obj.Child;
  }
}
```

Если хочется чтобы можно было создать объект одним выражением - то надо добавить `BindParents` возвращаемое значение:

```
var obj = BindParents(new MyClass
{
    Child = new MyClass
    {
        Child = new MyClass()
    }
});

// ...

static MyClass BindParents(MyClass root) {
  for (var obj = root; obj.Child != null; obj = obj.Child)
    obj.Child.Parent = obj;
  return root;
}
```

Comment: _"создать "прямую" структуру, а потом дополнить ее обратными связями"_ -- а не проще сразу создавать связи, как это сделано в System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList.AddLast?

Comment: @Stack от структуры зависит. Иногда проще, иногда нет.

Comment: @Stack, не проще в моем случае

Answer (score -2):

```
MyClass theMyClass = null;
        theMyClass = new MyClass
        {
            Parent = null,
            Child = new MyClass
            {
                Parent = theMyClass,
                Child = new MyClass()
                {
                    Parent = theMyClass.Child,
                }
            }
        };
```

Почему бы и нет?

Comment: Потому что работать не будет. Переменная `theMyClass` устанавливается уже после всех присвоений.

Comment: Тогда есть более тупой и хитрый вариант: формировать структуру от конца к началу, то есть начиная с детей. потом Parrent = new MyClass(){ Parrent = new MyClass() {........

Comment: У автора вопроса структура симметрична, так что там возникнет та же самая проблема :)

Comment: И правда, очень интересный вопрос... скорее всего так даже невозможно