# Алгоритм определения возможных замен ключевых компонентов

Tags: алгоритм, архитектура, проектирование, биллинг

*Задача о учёте материальных ценностей.*

Дано:

- Есть некая учётная система, ядро которой составляют **единицы учёта** (физические объекты, имеющие *инвентарные номера*).
- Единицы учёта могут быть **простыми** (*units*), или **составными** (*complexes*), состоящими из нескольких простых.
- Могут перемещаться как простые, так и составные единицы.
- Составные единицы могут быть разобраны, их компоненты могут быть заменены (например, во время ремонта).
- Как правило, существует по несколько единиц учёта одной **модели** (**типа, названия**, *lines*). Составные единицы учёта также имеют наименование.
- С моделями единиц учёта связаны **производители** (*producers*).
- Составные единицы учёта собираются согласно некоторому **прототипу** (**сценарию**, *prototype*), в котором указаны составляющие составную единицу учёта модели простых единиц учёта. При этом одна из моделей является **ключевой** - она определяет наименование составного прибора.
- Могут существовать **полуфабрикаты** единиц хранения, когда несколько компонентов объединены, но среди них нет ключевого (такие полуфабрикаты не имеют инвентарных номеров).

*Пример*

Компания предоставляет в аренду башенные краны. Готовый кран - это составная единица учёта. В аренду может быть сдан как готовый кран, так и его компоненты. Он состоит из некоторого набора простых компонентов (*подъёмная башня, поворотная стрела, стреловой полиспат* и проч.). У каждого компонента есть свое наименование и свой произодитель. Из имеющихся на складе компонентов можно собрать разные краны под конкретные задачи. Есть типовые решения, которые повторяются раз за разом. Допустим, есть несколько собранных кранов, которые отличаются только *кабиной* (ключевой компонент): обозначим их как К-1, К-2 и К-3. Фактически, **замена кабины превращает один кран в другой. Замена прочих компонентов на наименование крана не влияет**. Сборка-разборка достаточно трудоёмки, поэтому полностью краны не разбирают и на складе среди прочего хранятся "полуфабрикаты".

*Второй пример*

Некий фотограф владеет несколькими фотоаппаратами и аксессуарами к ним. *Фотоаппарат* - это составная единица хранения (состоит из *тушки, вспышки, объектива* и проч.). Тушка - *ключевой компонент* (конкретно для этого абстрактного фотографа!), её замена приводит к смене наименования собранного комплекта.

*Третий пример*

IT-отдел абстрактной компании, собирающий рабочие станции для сотрудников. Рабочая станция состоит из *монитора (мониторов), системного блока, клавиатуры, мыши* и еще чего-нибудь в зависимости от рода деятельности сотрудника. Системный блок - ключевой компонент.

*Дополнительные комментарии к задаче*

Данные хранятся в БД. В общих чертах структура такова:

```
producers (производители):
- id
- name (наименование производителя)

lines (модели):
- id
- id_producer (ID производителя)
- name (наименование модели)

units (единицы учёта):
- id 
- id_line (ID модели)
- id_bundle (ID набора, в который входит единица учёта)
- inv_num (инвентарный номер)

prototypes (прототипы):
- id_comlex (ID составной модели)
- id_component (ID модели-компонента)
- is_main_component (маркер ключевого компонента)

bundles (наборы единиц хранения)
- id
- id_complex_unit (ID составной единицы учёта, если полуфабрикат - то здесь NULL)
```

Таблица *lines* связана с таблицей *units* отношением *один-ко-многим*. Модели - это абстракция, единицы учёта - материальные объекты. Прототип - это описание "абстрактных" моделей, т.к. при сборке собственно не важно, какой именно из однотипных компонентов будет использован.

Таблица *producers* связана с таблицей *lines* отношением *один-ко-многим*.

Таблица *prototypes* связана с таблицей *lines* отношением *многие-кo-многим*. Одна модель простой единицы учёта может входить в несколько прототипов составных моделей. Один прототип включает в себя несколько моделей простых единиц учёта. По сути, таблица *prototypes* связывает таблицу *lines* с самой собой.

При составлении составной единицы учета пользователь выбирает нужный прототип, и в зависимости от входящих в него моделей выбирает свободные (не связанные, имеющиеся в наличии) простые единицы учета.

Если необходимо изменить состав составной единицы учета, то опять же согласно прототипу выбираются свободные единицы учёта и происходит замена.

*Важное уточнение*

При сборке и пересборке составной единицы учета для выбора доступны только единицы учёта входящих в прототип моделей. Нюанс в том, что при пересборке должны быть доступны ключевые компоненты других прототипов. Например, при пересборке крана К-1 из примера выше пользователь должен иметь возможность выбирать также и кабины для кранов К-2 и К-3 (три прототипа различаются только ключевым компонентом).

**Но вот как сделать, чтобы можно было при замене указать возможные ключевые компоненты?** Перебирать каждый раз все имеющиеся прототипы не хочется, т.к. потенциально их может быть очень много.

Comment: Очень странно выглядит line, вернее его жесткое участие в прототипе. Неужели у вас не бывает, что к конкретному крану подходят полиспасты разных производителей. Тут по моему напрашиваются какие то взаимозаменяемые типы компонентов и кабины так же относятся к этим взаимозаменяемым типам и выбор должен быть в пределах такого типа.

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за замечание. Я еще при написании вопроса хотел указать, что маркировки сознательно убраны из задачи, чтобы хоть немного её упростить. Да, конечно, возможны взаимозаменяемые модели разных производителей и все-таки в академических целях этим можно пренебречь.

Comment: А как сейчас реализуется замена взаимозаменяемых компонентов ? Я бы ими не стал пренебрегать ни в каких целях. потому как для их заменямости надо в прототипах держать не конкретный компонент а некую разновидность и уж больно кабины на такую разновидность смахивают. И еще я вдруг подумал, что странно выглядит один уровень сборки, неужели стрела в свою очередь не может состоять из передней части и противовеса

Comment: Сейчас система "пляшет" от ID составной учетной единицы - она привязана к модели, последняя обозначена как id_complex в таблице прототипов. Иными словами, определяется текущий прототип, по нему выбираются все доступные единицы хранения всех входящих в прототип моделей. Насчет составления сложных единиц из сложных (уровни сборки) согласен - это вполне возможно. Насчет разновидностей также согласен с вами.

Comment: Добавил еще два примера в задачу, чтобы не привязываться конкретно к строительной технике (хотя эта тема и позволила уточнить детали).

Comment: Давайте к кранам вернемся. у нас есть 2 заменяемых полиспаста модель ID1 и ID2 Вы сейчас можете создать прототип по которому можно взять либо один либо другой. Причем после выбора конкретного экземпляра модели ID1 у нас слот полиспастов в прототипе должен закрыться и мы второй такой же компонент поставить не можем (если конечно в прототипе явно это не разрешено), хоть он id1, хоть id2. ? Или вы будете делать 2 прототипа из за этого ?

Comment: Ок. Мы все-таки добавляем маркировки (и тогда они попадают между прототипами и моделями). И тогда конечно слот закрывается при выборе любой из моделей данной маркировки. При этом два прототипа не нужно.

Comment: Отлично, теперь прототипов меньше и у нас есть "маркировка" с названием "кабины бЕшенных кранов от 100 до 120 тонн". в нее входят несколько кабин, вот из них мы и выбираем любую модель и кран превращается ... превращается ... Или вам необходимо что бы при смене "типа" крана у него стал другой прототип. Мы же не коснулись момента откуда у крана берется название, которое от кабины зависит

Comment: В реальной боевой задаче (не с кранами) название связано с ключевым компонентом. Т.е. как только в состав собираемого крана попадает кабина, мы уже знаем название. Да, кран ещё не собран, но название уже есть. Если развивать тему кранов, то название даётся при полной сборке (либо даётся имеющееся), либо предлагается как-то назвать результат сборки.

Comment: @DenisKhvorostin _"как только в состав собираемого крана попадает кабина, мы уже знаем название."_ -- по идее с самого начала надо знать что собираете. например, начали собирать кран. собрали часть. оставили ее на складе. после выходных продолжили сборку. при этом всегда точно знаете что делать и где лежат компоненты. но также должна быть возможность получить ответ на вопрос: а что мы можем собрать из того что есть на складе?

Comment: @Stack, это верно. Строго говоря, речь о "рисовании форточек" для процесса пересборки или замены компонентов. В этой форме должны указываться все подходящие в имеющиеся "слоты" компоненты.

Comment: @DenisKhvorostin _"это верно. Строго говоря, речь о "рисовании форточек" для процесса пересборки"_ -- т.е. нужен UI в котором можно выбрать одну из моделей/типов. посмотреть структуру (т.е. из каких других моделей/типов состоит и посмотреть возможные замены в рамках данной структуры). при этом можно создать копию структуры, отредактировать и дать другое название. также для выбранной структуры можно посмотреть что из компонентов есть на складе и где оно находится и когда там оказалось. все это предусмотрено в схеме бд в моем [ответе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489438/196972).

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, надо выкинуть из задачи лишнее. И это лишнее, насколько мне видится - ключевые компоненты. Чем ключевые компоненты отличаются от остальных? Только тем, что влияют на наименование результата. Но есть ли в условии задачи хоть что-то про наименование? Нет. Значит, в рамках задачи поиска замены для компонента разделение компонентов на ключевые и неключевые бессмысленно, даже если пользователь считает иначе.

Выкидываем дальше. Если есть две детали одной модели, то чем они отличаются в плане пригодности для сборки? Только доступностью. В базе складского учета может быть написано что угодно, но для задачи нас интересуют только модели и сколько единиц какой модели есть на складе. Инвентарные номера - лишние. О них, как и о названиях, будут думать уже после сборки.

---

Теперь о том, чего в задаче не хватает. **В задаче остро не хватает ограничений.** В текущей формулировке ничто не мешает заменить абсолютно все детали (т.е. собрать совершенно новый кран) - и назвать подобную операцию "пересборкой". Скорее всего, строгих ограничений тут ввести и не получится (хотя дать пользователю выбрать, какие детали он менять *не* хочет - было бы отличной идеей). Значит, нужна целевая функция.

Иными словами, надо назначить каждой детали показатель "сложности" ее установки или демонтирования. Сложность можно оценивать как среднее время, затрачиваемое на эту операцию. Правда, такую точную статистику собрать вряд ли получится - так что придется прибегать к приближенным экспертным оценкам ("Михалыч, сколько времени тебе нужно чтобы вот эту хрень заменить?"). В дальнейшем, эти оценки можно корректировать по результатам работ.

Также, нужно как-то оценивать сложность изменения схемы сборки. Я думаю, существуют такие краны, что один в другой никак нельзя переделать не разбирая полностью, даже если они состоят из почти одинакового набора деталей. Сейчас у вас прототипы решают слишком много задач - их надо как-то разделить. Но об этом уже было в комментариях.

Фактически, именно эта часть - поиск ограничений и составление адекватной целевой функции - самая сложная. И тут по интернету чем-то помочь сложно. Это даже не программирование, это аналитика и работа с заказчиком.

---

Что же до алгоритма, то в общем случае алгоритм довольно простой. Перебираем все возможные варианты - и оцениваем их. Выбираем N самых лучших - и показываем их пользователю. 
Для ускорения поиска нужно отсекать те ветви, которые заведомо хуже уже найденных.

Если все сделано правильно - то поиск не должен быть долгим. На складе не может быть миллиона прототипов кранов, также как в компьютерном магазине не может быть миллиона прототипов компьютеров. К слову, "прототип компьютера" полностью задается материнской платой - поэтому их не может быть больше чем моделей материнских плат (и это *очень* грубая оценка, их куда меньше).

О конкретном алгоритме (что и в каком порядке перебирать) можно говорить только при наличии схемы данных, целевой функции и оценок по объемам данных.

Comment: Павел, спасибо за ответ. Занятно только, что тот нюанс, которому посвящен вопрос, вы посчитали лишним в задаче. Вернемся к истокам. Пусть будет по 3 компонента в составных приборах, одна из них - ключевая. Замена неключевых компонентов в ходе пересборки никак не влияет на наименование, но вот замена ключевого компонента - влияет. В общем, как-то не туда, по-моему.

Comment: @DenisKhvorostin в том-то и дело, что название дается уже по результатам сборки, никаких требований к названию в задаче в вашей формулировке не предъявляется. Потому тот факт, что компонент влияет на название - никак не влияет на сам алгоритм.

Comment: @PavelMayorov _"Чем ключевые компоненты отличаются от остальных?"_ -- например, двигатель в машине. он сильно влияет на все остальное. _"выкинуть из задачи лишнее."_ -- в задаче есть лишнее, но информацию о ключевом компоненте не надо выкидывать.

Comment: Это влияние никак не формализовано в условии задачи. Программирование - это не гадание на кофейной гуще. И я писал об этом: "*В задаче остро не хватает ограничений*"

Comment: @PavelMayorov _"Это влияние никак не формализовано в условии задачи."_ -- в вопросе сказано: "есть краны ... отличаются только кабиной (ключевой компонент): обозначим их как К-1, К-2 и К-3. Фактически, замена кабины превращает один кран в другой. Замена прочих компонентов на наименование крана не влияет". но это сказано в `Пример`, а не в `Дано` и получается, что да - формально оно не формализовано в условии.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, мне нравится ваш подход: вы придумали себе какой-то другой вопрос, успешно ответили на него, а меня упрекаете в недостатке формализма. Я несколько раз проговорил важность ключевого компонента, как в вопросах, так и в обсуждениях. Тут формализма - на несколько страниц А4 в нескольких ракурсах и с несколькими примерами. Плюс диалог в комментариях к вопросу. И если жирный текст в разделе ПРИМЕР вопроса (!), а также раздел ВАЖНОЕ УТОЧНЕНИЕ - это не формализованная задача - то что такое формализация?

Comment: @DenisKhvorostin но вы не ответили на вопрос "а в чем, собственно, проблема?". Без ответа на этот вопрос исходный вопрос теряет смысл, отсюда и додумывание. В своем ответе вы эту проблему продемонстрировали - и она стала понятна.

Comment: @DenisKhvorostin поскольку в диалоге с Mike вы согласились, что в схему надо добавить маркировки, они же слоты, между прототипами и моделями - я и подумать не мог, что введение слотов для ключевых компонентов составит проблему. Свой первый ответ я писал исходя из того, что такие слоты-маркировки уже введены.

Answer (score 1):

Кажется, я понял в чем заключается ваша проблема. Зря вы спрашивали про алгоритм - у вас проблема не в алгоритме, а в схеме данных.

> Теперь к сути вопроса
>
> Есть три наименования (а, б, в) составных прибора и вот их состав:
>
> - прибор а: ABCX
> - прибор б: ABCY
> - прибор в: ABCZ
>
> А, В, С, X, Y, Z - это модели компонентов. Первые три - встречаются во всех составных приборах, последние три - ключевые компоненты. Нюанс вот в чем: можно заменить X на Y и вместо прибора (а) получится прибор (б).
>
> Представьте форму выбора доступных компонентов. C A, B и С проблем нет: выбираем доступные юниты тех моделей, которые указаны в нашем прототипе. А вот с X, Y и Z возникает сложность - если отталкиваться от прототипа, то будут показаны юниты только одной модели, но физическая-то замена возможна! А значит, это можно как-то выразить и в коде.

Проблема в том, что имя у вас назначается прототипу, а потому нельзя сделать один прототип, куда можно было бы поставить разные ключевые компоненты.

Из требований ясно, что в итоге должно получиться что-то вроде такого:

- прибор N: ABCs, где s - слот, куда можно поставить X, Y или Z. Название N зависит от s.

Значит, надо придумать такую схему хранения, в которую бы такой прототип "влез". Кстати, удобно начинать схему хранения в объектном формате, а потом уже переходить от него к реляционному.

Вот мой вариант:

```
Прототип
  название (строка)
  слоты (массив типа Слот)

Слот
  варианты (массив типа ВариантСлота)

ГлавныйСлот (наследует Слот)
  варианты (массив типа ВариантГлавногоСлота)

ВариантСлота
  модель (Модель)

ВариантГлавногоСлота (наследует ВариантСлота)
  модель изделия (Модель)

Модель
  название (строка)
```

В этой схеме я оставил только то, что имеет отношение к задаче. Главное отличие - у прототипа больше нет идентификатора составной модели, связь с составной моделью имеет только ВариантГлавногоСлота.

В такой схеме пользователь сначала выбирает прототип, после чего может выбирать варианты для каждого слота. После выбора варианта главного слота у изделия появляется идентификатор модели и вместе с ним - название.

На реляционную БД такую схему можно переложить так:

```
Прототипы
  ИД
  Название

Слоты
  ИД
  ИДПрототипа (связь с таблицей Прототипы)
  ТипСлота (главный/не главный)

ВариантыСлота
  ИД
  ИДСлота (связь с таблицей Слоты)
  ИДМодели (связь с таблицей Модели)
  ИДМоделиИзделия (связь с таблицей Модели, опционально)

Модели
  ИД
  Название
```

Правда, такая структура БД не защищена от ошибок (так, нигде не проверяется, что у главного слота всем вариантам назначены модели изделия).

Поэтому продвинутый вариант будет выглядеть таким образом:

```
Прототипы
  ИД
  Название

Слоты
  ИД
  ИДПрототипа (связь с таблицей Прототипы)
  ТипСлота (главный/не главный)

ВариантыСлота
  ИД
  ИДСлота
  ИДМодели (связь с таблицей Модели)
  ИДМоделиИзделия (связь с таблицей Модели, опционально)
  ТипСлота (главный/не главный)
  * связь с таблицей Слоты по полям Слоты.(ИД, ТипСлота) - ВариантыСлота.(ИДСлота, ТипСлота)
  * ограничение: ИДМоделиИзделия заполнено тогда и только тогда, когда ТипСлота  - главный

Модели
  ИД
  Название
```

Здесь я добавил в варианты слота тип слота, и гарантировал совпадение типа слота для самого слота и его вариантов при помощи составного внешнего ключа.

Это позволило добавить ограничение (CHECK CONSTRAINT в SQL) на ИДМоделиИзделия.

Еще более строгий вариант, гарантирующий что у каждого прототипа только 1 главный слот, подразумевает выделение главных слотов в отдельную таблицу, с указанием отдельной ссылки на нее. Но так будет делать только очень неленивый человек (а я ленивый, потому такой вариант и не стал расписывать).

Comment: а если в Слот можно поставить сборный компонент (т.е. у него есть свои Слоты), то как это записать в базу? и как узнать сколько прототипов было разработано, например, в прошлом году?

Comment: @Stack это нужно у автора спросить. В комментариях выше он согласился, что слоты таки нужны. Мое предложение - лишь в том, чтобы ключевой компонент тоже помещать в слот, и я показал как "обычную" модель со слотами расширить до модели, где решена проблема "выделенности" ключевых компонентов.

Comment: _"согласился, что слоты таки нужны."_ -- если считать что есть реальный объект, то да - в нем "слот".  но надо отделить информацию о типе. например, если взять "схему хранения в объектном формате", то на c# будет что-то вроде `class Element { int Id; string Name; bool IsKey; List<Element> Elements; }`. и также будет `val all = new List<Element>() ;` т.е. можно найти все модели и получить из каких других Element'ов они состоят. и найти ключевые компоненты. при этом на складе могут лежать коробки, с ссылками на модель (т.е. написан определенный Element.Id). и вроде все понятно и без слотов.

Answer (score -1):

Если информацию о компонентах хранить в таблицах с nested relations, то будете знать какой компонент можно разобрать и из каких частей он состоит и какой из компонентов яляется ключевым.
Если надо знать какие из компонентов можно заменить на другие, то надо добавить таблицу с информацией об альтернативах.

```
producers 
    id
    name

models       -- модели (простые и составные компоненты) + прототип 
    id  
    name 
    producer : ref producers.id
    parent : ref models.id
    iskey : bool     -- true для ключевого компонента
    meta   -- сценарий для монтажа компонента
    created : datetime  -- дата создания/регистрации модели

alts
    id
    parent : ref models.id  -- компонент
    model : ref models.id   -- возможная замена для компонента

units      -- единицы учета
    id     
    model : ref models.id
    created : datetime      -- дата регистрации/приемки единицы на учет
    released : datetime is null  -- дата продажи. если null, то есть в наличии.

store       -- склад
    id
    place : ref places.id     -- ссылка на место хранения
    unit : ref units.id       -- ссылка на единицу учета  
    created : datetime   -- дата размещения unit'а на этом place

places     -- места хранения на складе
    id     -- пример: 20411205 (2-здание, 04-помещение, 112-стеллаж, 05-полка)
    params  -- параметры места
```

При сборке надо выбрать из models необходимый компонент, а также вложенные компоненты. Затем из store и units выбрать все соответствующие компоненты и альтернативы, у которых released is null.

У составных компонентов есть потомки (компоненты, у которых parent равен id выбранного компонента).

В итоге, на UI видна вся иерархия из которых состоит компонент.
Виден ключевой компонент (iskey == true). Также для каждого компонента можно посмотреть альтернативные варианты и есть ли они в налиции.

Если в сборочном цехе из разных компонентов создается полуфабрикат, то фактически это новая модель, ее можно "положить в коробку" и отправить на склад, где будет присвоен номер и определено место хранения.

---

Пример таблицы с nested relations

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подробнее [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/478676/196972).

Comment: если база данных находится в SQL Server, то для работы с иерархическими данными можно использовать тип [hierarchyid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb677290(v=sql.120).aspx)

Comment: вижу минус :) интересно, за что? тов. минусаторы, ставить минус без комментария - считается дурным тоном.

Answer (score -1):

Прежде всего проговорю главное:

1. Наличие ключевого компонента, - это важно.
2. Инвентарные номера также важны.

В последнее время я все больше и больше склоняюсь к **идее разведения материальных объектов и объектов учёта в разные (хотя и связанные) сущности**. Для меня как разработчика это было далеко не очевидно — ведь в БД есть таблица инвентаризуемых объектов, и решение добавить дополнительное поле с инвентарным номером просто напрашивается сама собой. И вот вдруг до меня доходит, что так делать не нужно.

*Метафора (паттерн): инвентарный номер — коробка*

Инвентарный номер — это своего рода **коробка**, в которую складываются физические предметы: один или несколько. При этом некий объект может одновременно находиться в нескольких коробках (коробки вкладываются одна в другую):

- *инвентаризация* в этом ключе — это помещение материального объекта в коробку.
- *сборка составного прибора* — помещение нескольких коробок в одну коробку большего размера.
- *пересборка прибора* — перемещение компонентов из одной коробки в другую.
- *разбор прибора* — извлечение коробок из одной большой.

Если развить метафору коробки, получается, что при сборке/пересборке мы отталкиваемся от ярлыков на вложенных коробках. При этом итоговое наименование может составляться из наименований всех вложенных компонентов, или формироваться по некоторым ключевым признакам/ключевым компонентам:

> DELL INSPIRON Mini 1018 (Atom N455 1660 Mhz/10.1"/1024x600/1024Mb/160Gb/DVD нет/Wi-Fi/Win 7 Starter)

Если три из четырех компонентов составных приборов не отличаются в разных модификациях, то указывать их в составном приборе нет смысла. Отсюда идея ключевого компонента.

*Теперь к сути вопроса*

Есть три *наименования* (а, б, в) составных прибора и вот их состав:

1. прибор а: ABCX
2. прибор б: ABCY
3. прибор в: ABCZ

А, В, С, X, Y, Z - это модели компонентов. Первые три - встречаются во всех составных приборах, последние три - ключевые компоненты. Нюанс вот в чем: можно заменить X на Y и вместо прибора (а) получится прибор (б).

Представьте форму выбора доступных компонентов. C A, B и С проблем нет: выбираем доступные юниты тех моделей, которые указаны в нашем прототипе. А вот с X, Y и Z возникает сложность - если отталкиваться от прототипа, то будут показаны юниты только одной модели, но физическая-то замена возможна! А значит, это можно как-то выразить и в коде.

Прототип составного прибора и модели приборов связаны отношением многие-ко-многим. При этом в каждом из прототипов есть один ключевой компонент. Для описанной в вопросе структуры БД можно сделать такой запрос:

```
    SELECT m.id_component, 
           h.others
      FROM prototypes m
INNER JOIN (SELECT id_composite, 
                   group_concat(id_component) others
      FROM prototypes
     WHERE is_key_component = 0
  GROUP BY id_composite) h USING (id_composite)
     WHERE m.is_key_component = 1
```

Этот запрос составляет пары ключевых компонентов и слитых в строку прочих компонентов. Собственно, стоит добавить в условие отбора перечень идентификаторов составных компонентов и это решит задачу определения подходящих ключевых компонентов (только нужно будет добавить сортировку).

Comment: _"склоняюсь к идее разведения материальных объектов и объектов учёта в разные (хотя и связанные) сущности."_ -- согласен. когда из фуры достают коробку/объект, то на складе должны присвоить этой коробке инвентарный номер. и положить эту коробку в определенное место на складе. поэтому у меня в ответе есть models, units (инвентарные номера) и store (движение по местам хранения на складе)

Comment: _"Прототип составного прибора и модели приборов связаны отношением многие-ко-многим"_ -- представьте модель (от производителя A) можно разобрать на другие компоненты. но такая же модель (от производителя Б) не разбирается на части. с другой стороны, компоненты от разных производителей можно собрать в один составной компонент, и производителем становится тот кто ее собрал, т.е. ваша компания. в итоге, создавать отдельную таблицу для прототипов не нужно, т.к. всю информацию о моделях и их составляющих можно держать в одной таблице c nested relations.

Comment: Это не ответ на вопрос. Вам следует отредактировать сам вопрос, а не писать дополнения в форме ответа.

Comment: _"можно заменить X на Y и вместо прибора (а) получится прибор (б)."_ -- это больше похоже на создание прибора (б), а не на замену. заменить можно колесо у машины на запасное. но если вы меняете двигатель с обычного на форсированный, то получаете другую машину.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, это-то как раз ответ. Видите в конце ответа SQL-запрос и комментарий к нему? Фактически, это то, что помогло решить задачу без переделывания структуры БД. Не идеальный вариант, но рабочий.

Comment: @DenisKhvorostin _"Видите в конце ответа SQL-запрос и комментарий к нему? Фактически, это то, что помогло решить задачу без переделывания структуры БД."_ -- т.е. большой вопрос и  примеры и вот это все было не про структуру базы и т.д., а про то как для пары таблиц написать SQL запрос? :)

Comment: @DenisKhvorostin в таком случае, ответ, получается, частично содержит уточнения к вопросу. В итоге, ответ идет не вполне на тот самый вопрос, который задавался. По крайней мере, я смог понять в чем у вас вообще проблема только после вашего ответа.

Comment: @Stack для специалистов - так и есть. Но для обычных смертных, автомобиль определяется корпусом. А для некоторых - так вообще шильдиком :) Поэтому клиент вполне может потребовать: а замените мне в машине двигатель! И если такая замена возможна - то эту операцию надо как-то в интерфейсе реализовывать.