# Манипуляции с List<DTO> и datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagrid

Есть модели:

```
public class Examiner
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Consultation> Consultations { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Exam> Exams { get; set; }

    public Examiner()
    {
        Consultations = new List<Consultation>();
        Exams = new List<Exam>();
    }  
}

public class Exam
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int MinGrade { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Examiner> Examiners { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Result> Results { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; } 

    public Exam()
    {
        Examiners = new List<Examiner>();
        Results = new List<Result>();
        Questions = new List<Question>();
    } 

}
```

Есть DTO

```
 public class ExamDTO
{
    public ExamDTO(Exam exam)
    {
        Id = exam.Id;
        Name = exam.Name;
        Date = exam.Date;
        MinGrade = exam.MinGrade;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int MinGrade { get; set; }
}

public class ExaminerDTO
{
    public ExaminerDTO(Examiner examiner)
    {
        Id = examiner.Id;
        FullName = examiner.FullName;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

Есть методы поиска и извлечения через Unit of Work:

```
public IEnumerable<ExamDTO> GetExams(int id = 0, string name = null, DateTime date = new DateTime(),
        int examinerId = 0,
        int enrolleeId = 0, int resultId = 0, int questionId = 0)
    {
        var list =
            new List<ExamDTO>(
                UnitOfWork.Exams.Find(
                    e =>
                        (id == 0 || e.Id == id) && (name == null || e.Name == name) &&
                        (date == default(DateTime) || e.Date == date) &&
                        (examinerId == 0 ||
                         e.Examiners.Contains(UnitOfWork.Examiners.Get(examinerId)) &&
                         (enrolleeId == 0 ||
                          e.Results.Contains(
                              UnitOfWork.Results.Find(r => r.ExamId == e.Id && r.EnrolleeId == enrolleeId)
                                  .SingleOrDefault()) &&
                          (resultId == 0 || e.Results.Contains(UnitOfWork.Results.Get(resultId))) &&
                          (questionId == 0 || e.Questions.Contains(UnitOfWork.Questions.Get(questionId))))))
                    .Select(s => new ExamDTO(s)));
        if (list.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }
        return list;
    }

 public IEnumerable<ExaminerDTO> GetExaminers(int id = 0, int examId = 0, int consId = 0, string name = null)
    {
        var list =
            new List<ExaminerDTO>(
                UnitOfWork.Examiners.Find(
                    e =>
                        (id == 0 || e.Id == id) &&
                        (examId == 0 ||
                         e.Exams.Contains(UnitOfWork.Exams.Get(examId)) &&
                         (consId == 0 || e.Consultations.Contains(UnitOfWork.Consultations.Get(consId))) &&
                         (name == null || e.FullName == name))).Select(s => new ExaminerDTO(s)));
        if (list.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

У меня получилось привязать List к DataGridView

```
private IExamService service; 
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        service = new ExamService(new EFUnitOfWork(@"data source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=ExamCom.DAL.ECContext;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"));
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource()
        {
            DataSource = service.GetExams()
        };
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
    }
```

Собственно вот форма: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне описать событие SeceltionChanged первого datagridview, чтобы при выборе определенного экзамена в нем я мог извлечь выбранный экземпляр и аналогичным образом запихнуть во второй DataGridView связанные с ним данные, в данном случае экзаменаторов? Или возможно есть идеи более оптимального решения?

Comment: посмотрите ответ на вопрос [Как привязать контролы к данным?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478616)

Comment: если данные находятся в (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB и выводятcя в DataGridView, то для чего вам DTO-классы? данные надо загружать в DataSet и его привязать к DataGridView

Comment: Не согласен с Stack, используйте DTO, в этом нет никакой проблемы. А вот код по ссылке в принципе вполне понятно вроде отображает, как можно сделать проброс данных.

Comment: @Monk _"используйте DTO, в этом нет никакой проблемы"_ -- данные из базы приходят как object.  вы определяете в коде несколько DTO.   затем object раскладываете по свойствам, чтобы DataGridView прочел свойства как object'ы и вывел на экран. это немного бессмысленно. в .net  существует механизм привязки данных, который используется в вопросе, но только частично.

Comment: @Stack, не могли бы вы объяснить этот код из примера по ссылке:

 f.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { l3, l2, l1, t });
        foreach (var g in f.Controls.OfType<DataGridView>())
            g.BindingContext[g.DataSource, g.DataMember].CurrentItemChanged += 
                (s, e) => t.Text = Model.GetXml(d);
        f.ShowDialog();

В начале на форму добавляются созданные ранее контролы, а что происходит далее?

Comment: @Сергей _" на форму добавляются созданные ранее контролы, а что происходит далее?"_ -- изменение текущего элемента данных (например после добавения  новуй строки в DataGridView) перехватывается и в обработчике создается новый xml, который выводится в textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В событии SelectionChanged первого грида можно просто обозначать содержимое второго, так же, как вы делаете это с первым:

```
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource()
    {
        DataSource = тут сами преобразуете данные с выбранного элемента в коллекцию для второго грида
    };
    dataGridView2.DataSource = bs;
```